# sql start with and end with

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to find the string start with D or K and end with 2 or 3 in Oracle SQL using `regexp_like()` function.

REGEXP_LIKE (Attribute, '(^D|^K)') shows

```
DL71
DR93
DW11
KL62
KT03
KV29
```

REGEXP_LIKE (Attribute, '(^D|^K)*') shows

```
AT94
BV06
CD52
DL71
DR93
DW11
FD21
KL62
KT03
KV29
```

REGEXP_LIKE (Attribute, '*(^2|^3)') shows

```
CD52
DR93
KL62
KT03
```

REGEXP_LIKE (Attribute, '(^D|^K)*(^2|^3)') shows

```
CD52 
DR93
KL62        
KT03
```

**How should I correct it?**

The data is as following:

```
Attribute
AT94
BV06
CD52
DL71
DR93
DW11
FD21
KL62
KT03
KV29
```

Comment: Do you want to match `D...2` and `D...3`? Or `D...2` and `K...3`? You have not shown the expected result.

Comment: Your final attempt comes really close; you must come from a UNIX background, where `*` means "anything". In proper regular expressions, `.` stands for any single character (except perhaps newline, unless you use some options), and `*` simply means "zero or more occurrences". Besides that, you can factor out `^` in the first two tokens, so you could write `^(D|K)`, and similar at the end of the regexp. Finally, if the alternation is just between single characters, you can also write it as a character class. `(D|K)` is the same as `[DK]`. This will now be exactly Gordon Linnoff's answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Attribute, '^[DK].*[23]$')
```

You are looking for character classes.  These are delimited by square braces.

The regular expression:

- `^` at the beginning of the pattern means that the expression starts with the pattern.
- `[DK]` is a character class matching exactly one occurrence of one of these characters.
- `.*` matches any number of characters (newlines might be an issue).
- `[23]` is a character class matching exactly one of these characters.
- `$` at the end of the pattern means that the expression ends with this pattern -- in this case, `2` or `3` at the end.

Comment: ^ stands for starting and $ stands for ending isnot it???? though i didnt checked it i gave it aan upvote

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression; you can just use `LIKE`:

```
WHERE ( Attribute LIKE 'D%' OR Attribute LIKE 'K%' )
AND   ( Attribute LIKE '%2' OR Attribute LIKE '%3' )
```

Comment: You don't ***need*** either RegExp or Like, both are options.  In this case I'd suggest RegExp is a perfectly fine solution.  *(Sure, regular expressions can get crazy hard to interpret, but in this case it looks fine...)*

Comment: @MatBailie A regular expression won't use an index on the `Attribute` column - you would need a function-based index. `LIKE` will use the index on the conditions where the leading character is not `%` or `_` - so can use an index to filter on the first two conditions.

Comment: @MT0 - as far as I understand, an `OR` condition will also prevent the use of an index; so even if the only test was `attribute like 'D%' or attribute like 'K%'`, a standard index on `attribute` would still not be used. Even so, though, `like` conditions may be one order of magnitude faster than regular expression conditions (although perhaps somewhat less that that in this special case, since the regexp is very simple).

Comment: @mathguy in my crude test, the `OR` does seem to be enough to force a scan : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0128d/3 . In which case the regular expression version and the LIKE version have approximately the same cost *(Although a regular expression **can** have a larger scalar calculation cost, it's not necessarily true, is unlikely to be an order of magnitude as it's a single expression vs four expressions, and everything will be dominated by the reads from the index anyway.)*

Comment: I guess that means using `UNION ALL` might perform better than `OR`?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0128d/6